# Intermittent NXDOMAIN responses for certain records with low TTLs

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We're experiencing a peculiar issue with our `bind` installation (version 9.8.4).

In this scenario, `bind` is configured as a caching name server for a small network. For the large majority of queries, everything works fine.

However, we've noticed that queries for some hosts that are configured with a very low TTL, we sometimes get NXDOMAIN responses even though the host name exists.

As an example, take *www.cdn77.com*—here's the output of `dig` when run on the name server itself:

```
$ dig www.cdn77.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> www.cdn77.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34440
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cdn77.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cdn77.com.      196 IN  CNAME   1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.
1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org. 0 IN  A   185.59.220.12

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
org.            170517  IN  NS  a2.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            170517  IN  NS  c0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            170517  IN  NS  b0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            170517  IN  NS  d0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            170517  IN  NS  a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            170517  IN  NS  b2.org.afilias-nst.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a0.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  A   199.19.56.1
a0.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  AAAA    2001:500:e::1
a2.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  A   199.249.112.1
a2.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  AAAA    2001:500:40::1
b0.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  A   199.19.54.1
b0.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  AAAA    2001:500:c::1
b2.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  A   199.249.120.1
b2.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  AAAA    2001:500:48::1
c0.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  A   199.19.53.1
c0.org.afilias-nst.info. 170517 IN  AAAA    2001:500:b::1
d0.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  A   199.19.57.1
d0.org.afilias-nst.org. 170517  IN  AAAA    2001:500:f::1

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 14:27:03 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 487
```

And here's an example of when a NXDOMAIN response is returned:

```
$ dig www.cdn77.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> www.cdn77.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 28771
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cdn77.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cdn77.com.      327 IN  CNAME   1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cdn77.org.      59  IN  SOA ns1.cdn77.org. admin.cdn77.com. 1449062655 10800 180 604800 60

;; Query time: 34 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 14:24:52 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 115
```

We use Google's public name servers as forwarders, and they never seem to respond with NXDOMAIN:

```
$ dig www.cdn77.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> www.cdn77.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35091
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cdn77.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cdn77.com.      851 IN  CNAME   1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.
1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org. 0 IN  A   185.59.220.11

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 14:29:16 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

The authoritive answer, by the way, looks like this:

```
$ dig 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11529
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org. 1 IN  A   185.59.220.12

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 37.235.105.100#53(37.235.105.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 14:32:57 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

Interestingly, even though the authorative TTL for the record is one, Google's public nameserver always reduces it to zero (see [this article](https://00f.net/2011/11/17/how-long-does-a-dns-ttl-last/) for an interesting read about this behavior). I don't think this has anything to do with the problem though, as the successful responses from our `bind` also show TTL zero.

I've increased `bind`'s logging level, but find it very hard to identify any entries that might have something to do with the problem. Even with `querylog` activated, all that's visible is the query itself and `resolver: debug 1: createfetch: 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org A` lines.

Any pointers towards how to better diagnose (or even solve) this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can reproduce the same thing, after watching the logs (verbosity 4), i noticed that the NXDOMAIN being cached is only being returned by Googles IPv6 2001:4860:4860::8844, whereas 8.8.8.8 consistently works.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening—thanks alot! Please make sure to put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: i'm hesitant to put it as an answer, because i'm still not sure why its happening - likely a stale cache, but its odd that ip6 alone cached specifically an nxdomain

Comment: I think "Remove the IPv6 addresses of Google's public name servers from your forwarders list." is a perfectly good answer to my question. :) But it's up to you, of course. Thanks again, this was driving me nuts.

Comment: i should have hesitated :)   I'd accept Alex's answer - i'm glad I could help, but his is the best answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the authoritative nameservers for cdn77.org fail to properly handle [ECS](http://www.afasterinternet.com/howitworks.htm) ([EDNS Client-Subnet](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-edns-client-subnet-04)) options when they contain an IPv6 client subnet, although they handle IPv4 client subnets just fine.

If you build [dig with EDNS client-subnet support](https://www.gsic.uva.es/%7Ejnisigl/dig-edns-client-subnet.html), you can check this on the command line; or you can use the online [KeyCDN DNS Lookup tool](https://tools.keycdn.com/dig) to check this (select the details checkbox and de-select the recursive checkbox, and omit the @ before ns1 when you give it as Custom DNS):

```
$ dig 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org +subnet=2001:db8::1
; <<>> DiG 9.10.1 <<>> +additional 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org +subnet=2001:db8::1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 44989
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1680
; CLIENT-SUBNET: 2001:db8::1/128/0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cdn77.org.      60  IN  SOA ns1.cdn77.org. admin.cdn77.com. 1449094813 10800 180 604800 60

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 37.235.105.100#53(37.235.105.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 02 22:21:41 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132
```

The same query with an IPv4 client address works just fine:

```
$ dig 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org +subnet=192.0.2.1
; <<>> DiG 9.10.1 <<>> +additional 1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org @ns1.cdn77.org +subnet=192.0.2.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19104
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1680
; CLIENT-SUBNET: 192.0.2.1/32/32
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1669655317.rsc.cdn77.org. 1 IN  A   185.93.3.27

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 37.235.105.100#53(37.235.105.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 02 22:42:13 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 81
```

When you send your query to an IPv6 address for Google Public DNS, your client IP subnet is of course an IPv6 subnet, and when the authoritative server answers NXDOMAIN, the (cached?) answer for IPv6 clients is NXDOMAIN too.  If you send your query to an IPv4 address for Google Public DNS, your client subnet is an IPv4 subnet, and you get the correct (possibly cached) answer.

Comment: Great answer, that certainly explains the discrepancy. I'm surprised Google doesn't ensure consistent data across servers...and seems like quite an oversight for cdn77 (and perhaps google) considering, for example, Unbound's default config includes ip4 & ip6 in round robin.

Comment: The EDNS client-subnet (ECS) field is a reflection of the client address, which is different when it uses IPv4 or IPv6. Even if both queries are handled by the exact same server, the ECS tag will direct them to different cached data - and that is the correct thing to do, as ECS is typically enabled only for nameservers that are doing GeoIP and returning different answers depending on the client IP address.

Answer (score 3):

The upstream forwarders seem to have inconsistent data - <strike>*although the cause of which is not clear*</strike> - one forwarder in your round-robin is returning `NXDOMAIN` which is being cached locally:

Google's Public DNS IPv6 `2001:4860:4860::8888` is currently returning `NXDOMAIN`, despite `8.8.8.8` working correctly *(ie., matching the Authoritative Answer)*

The short-term solution is to remove the offending forwarder, then restart Bind or clear the negative cache.

---

***See Alex Dupuy's answer for a clear explanation of the root cause***

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the inconvenience, this bug has been causing problems only to a handful of our clients, Alex Dupuy has provided great explanation of the problem. We have added IPv6 EDNS support and enabled IPv6 anycast on our DNS servers and this problem is now gone.